# unit testing angular 2(ionic 2) custom directive

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, ionic2, testbed

I made a custom directive for text masking in my ionic application. The directive is for input text masking for the phone number.
It uses `ngControl` to get and set the values of the input field.

```
@HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])
onKeyUp($event: any) {
        var inputValue = this.ngControl.control.value;   
        this.ngControl.control.setValue(this.getMaskedValue(inputValue));
    }
}
```

I tried many approaches to test it but I was unable to set the value. I was able to get `ngControl` by importing the `FormsModule` and binding the input.

But I still can't get value as `this.ngControl.control.value`. When I type in the input field, it works fine but unable to define test case.

here is the test case snippet

```
it('should have masked value', () => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  let element = inputEl.nativeElement;
  element.value = '999';
  inputEl.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup', key));
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(element.value).toEqual('(999)');
  });
}
```

This is my test component :

```
@Component({
  template: `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="val"   customDirective="(999)-999-9999">`
})
class TestCustomDirectiveComponent {
  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
  val = '';
}
```

I want to write a test case like this `expect(element.value).toEqual('(999)-999-9999`. How can I test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply overwrite the object.

```
it('should have masked value', () => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  let element = inputEl.nativeElement;
  Object.defineProperty(
    directive.ngControl.control,
    'value',
    { writable: true, value: 'your value' }
  );
  directive.onKeyUp(null);
  expect(element.value).toEqual('(999)');
}
```

(I assume you have a reference to your directive through the variable `directive`)

Comment: I was just missing the reference to the directive. Thanks a lot!